# equivalent "echo on" for linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, echo

How can I get to stdout all commands that run in bash script?

That is output must contain commands output AND commands themselves.

I found

```
#!/bin/bash -x
```

but this is not exactly the same because instead of

```
 mysql -v dbname < dump.sql | grep "CREATE TABLE"
```

it shows

```
+ mysql -v dbname
+ grep 'CREATE TABLE'
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use `bash -v`.

This is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash -v

echo "Hello, World" | sed 's|Hello|Goodbye|'

echo "Done."
```

This is the output:

```
#!/bin/bash -v

echo "Hello, World" | sed 's|Hello|Goodbye|'
Goodbye, World

echo "Done."
Done.
```

Unfortunately, there is no special marker like `PS4` for printing expanded commands. You could combine both though to quickly identify commands:

```
#!/bin/bash -vx

echo "Hello, World" | sed 's|Hello|Goodbye|'
+ echo 'Hello, World'
+ sed 's|Hello|Goodbye|'
Goodbye, World

echo "Done."
+ echo Done.
Done.
```

Answer (score 19):

set -x is other way of doing it.

```
$ cat a.sh
#!/bin/bash

set -x
echo "Hello, World" | sed 's|Hello|Goodbye|'
echo "Done."
```

Output will be:

```
sh a.sh
+ echo 'Hello, World'
+ sed 's|Hello|Goodbye|'
Goodbye, World
+ echo Done.
Done.
```

Comment: Which is kind of what the OP dismissed as useless right in his question...

Comment: @Ashok Could you please explain? I can't see the difference:
[here](http://pastebin.com/AParHsuA)

p.s.: GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (i486-pc-linux-gnu)
Ubuntu 10.04.3

Comment: @Putnik It's the same basic thing, but you can `set -x` anywhere in the script, and even deactivate it again. So if you only want it on the `echo "Done"` line, put `set -x` just before that one.

Comment: landed here through a search engine, found your answer helpful. Thx

Answer (score 7):

`set -x` is an equivalent of "echo on"

`set +x` is an equivalent of "echo off"

Comment: landed here through a search engine, found your answer helpful. Thx